# Keypress Gestures using Tampermonkey for Chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a tampermonkey userscript to replace a feature that existed with FireGestures back in Pre-Quantum Firefox. The ability to open all hovered links into new background tabs. So having a combination keypress, which in FG was Ctrl + Right Click and drawing a gesture trail though every link you wanted open. Everything I have so far has been written for me by somebody else so I'm not trying to take credit and I in am way over my head. I don't have the know-how to edit and fix what is needed. This is what I have so far.

```
(function(delay, t, lnk, clicked) {

  //config: delay before click. mouse movement will reset the delay timer.
  delay = 1000; //in milliseconds. 1sec = 1000ms

  t = 0;

  function mousemove() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    if (lnk) t = setTimeout(clickLink, delay);
  }

  function clickLink() {
    removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    clearTimeout(t);
    if (lnk) {
      lnk.target = "_blank";
        lnk.click();
        lnk.target = "";
      clicked = true;
    }
  }

  addEventListener("mouseover", function(ev, el, el2) {
    el = ev.target;
    removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    clearTimeout(t);
    while (el) {
      if (el.tagName === "A") {
        el2 = el;
        if (el !== lnk) {
          lnk = el;
          clicked = false;
          addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
          clearTimeout(t);
          t = setTimeout(clickLink, delay);
        }
        return;
      }

      el = el.parentNode;
    }
    if (!el2) {
      lnk = null;
      clicked = false;
      removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
      clearTimeout(t);
    }
  });

})();
```

There is a couple issues I face. 
1. This doesn't require any sort of button combination. It is continually active and will click any link that is hovered over for the specified length of time. I would prefer it to only function when a button combination is pressed, ideally Ctrl + Rightclick. I found a thread dealing with combination keypresses but wouldn't know how to edit it and insert it into the existing script to fit my needs.

```
document.addEventListener ("keydown", function (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.ctrlKey  &&  zEvent.altKey  &&  zEvent.code === "KeyE") {
        // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    }
} );
```

2. The pop-up blocker in chrome actually prevents these tabs from opening. I don't know if there is any way of remedying this other than turning off the pop-up blocker, but if there was I'd appreciate the help
3. This script opens up tabs in the foreground rather than the background. So opening up a bunch of links on a page wouldn't be possible because it would navigate to the new tab as soon as the first link is clicked. My original idea for fixing this was to just have the script just do a middle-click mouse event over every link it passed over, but I don't even know if that is something that is possible or practical. 
I know I am asking a lot but I was just hoping that someone out there that knows what they are doing could help me out by either editing what I already have or writing something out themselves. I appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

here's my spin on it. This is toggled rather than going on while you are holding onto the keys.

you could had the following to your TamperMonkey script, and when you press "Ctrl + Alt + S", the links on the page are modified and appended a `onmouseover` event. when you hit the key combination again, the event gets removed from the link. Short and simple.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (zEvent) {
  if (zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.altKey && zEvent.code === 'KeyS') {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    console.log(links.length);//how many links have been grabbed
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      if (links[i].onmouseover !== null && links[i].onmouseover.toString().indexOf('function openit') > -1)
      {
        //toggling the funcitonality off
        //remove it
        links[i].setAttribute('target', '');
        links[i].setAttribute('onmouseover', '');
      } 
      else
      {
        //toggling the funcitonality on
        //add it
        links[i].setAttribute('target', 'blank');
        links[i].setAttribute('onmouseover', 'function openit(elem){console.log(\'userScript will click on the link\');elem.click();};openit(this);');
      }
    }
  }
}
);
```

As for popup blocking... I don't know.

Comment: I created a new userscript to test what you had here and these were my results. I use the toggle combination to activate the script which worked as intended. As soon as I pass over a link it will open up a tab in the foreground. Upon returning to the original tab the toggle is still active and I can continue with hovering over other links but rather than opening new tabs it will just navigate to those links in the background inside that previously created tab. So it creates one new tab and that tab will just continue to navigate to every link I pass over. Am I making sense? It is interesting